# Python change 2 list using 1 variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have 2 lists. In my code I want to perform some actions on the list by using a single variable `board`. I need to do this as the actual code I use looks different but this simplification has the same functionality.

```
BOARD_SIZE = 5

# Create empty list
empty_board = [[0 for i in range(BOARD_SIZE)] for j in range(BOARD_SIZE)]

board1 = empty_board.copy()
board2 = empty_board.copy()

board = board1.copy()

board[1][1] = 1
board1 = board.copy()

board = board2.copy()
board[0][0] = 1
board2 = board.copy()

print(f"board1: {board1}")
print(f"board2: {board2}")
```

This gives me 2 identical list tho.

```
board1: [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
board2: [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

So what should I do to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Use `deepcopy` from the library `copy`, e.g. `from copy import deepcopy` then `board = deepcopy(board1)` etc. Deepcopy will create an entirely new copy in memory of the list that can be modified. `list.copy()` only creates a reference in memory to the original list, therefore when you modify the original list, all copies are also modified.

Comment: Okay thank you will try. I thought list.copy() would actually do what it says and not create a reference to the list

Comment: I might be wrong, that's why I kept it as a comment. Try it out. :)

Comment: As @slapslash says, `copy` creates a copy of the outer list, but that new outer list contains references to the same inner list objects. For example, with the code in your question, try `board1 is board2` (that will be False) and `board1[0] is board2[0]` (that will be True).

Answer (score 0):

> copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in the original.
> [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html)

So using `copy` instead of `deepcopy` only creates a copy of the outer list, while the inner lists are references. If you modify an item in the inner lists, it will also modify the original board.

But if you *replace* an inner list, it won't modify the original board:

```
empty_board = [[1,2],[3,4]]

board1 = empty_board.copy()
board2 = empty_board.copy()

board = board1.copy()

board[1] = [99, 99]
board1 = board.copy()

board = board2.copy()
board[0] = [99, 99]
board2 = board.copy()

print(f"board1: {board1}")
print(f"board2: {board2}")
```

will output:

```
board1: [[1, 2], [99, 99]]
board2: [[99, 99], [3, 4]]
```